# How to set header key and value with go packages : shurcooL/graphql or hasura/go-graphql-client?

Tags: go, graphql, http-headers, hasura

So I want to query datas from Graphql server via Go with either shurcool or hasura go client (Go packages), but the datas server required something like 'x-hasura-admin-secret' key and value includes inside a request header.

There's no mentioned in the both packages docs of how to do this (set header key & value), it only mentioned how to set access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client provided by https://github.com/hasura/go-graphql-client has a `WithRequestModifier` method. You could add a request header like so:

```golang
import (
    "net/http"
    graphql "github.com/hasura/go-graphql-client"
)

func gqlInit() {
    client := graphql.NewClient("your graphql url here", nil)
    client = client.WithRequestModifier(func(r *http.Request) {
        r.Header.Set("x-hasura-admin-secret", "secret")
    })
}
```

Looking at https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql and the related [github lib](https://github.com/shurcooL/githubv4), it seems like they expect you to pass an `*http.Client` that will add the header for you, you could do that like so:

```golang
import (
    "net/http"
    graphql "github.com/shurcooL/graphql"
)

type hasuraAuthTransport struct {
    secret string
}

func (h hasuraAuthTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    req.Header.Set("x-hasura-admin-secret", h.secret)
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}

func gqlInit() {
    client := graphql.NewClient("your graphql url here", &http.Client{
        Transport: hasuraAuthTransport{secret: "secret"},
    })
}
```

Comment: So this means you have to create a new client for every request right with the shurcooL package.

Comment: @NickN. no, one http client for every graphql client. you can re-use the client for the next request